# how to add specific links to search keywords

Tags: javascript, html

This is a search code i am working on but I want to give specific links to the members of the array 'people' so that 'rock' would have its own link to another page, 'brock', would have its own link and so on, the search is working perfectly but a i want the result to link to other pages

[image]
[image]
*here is the code(without html)*

```
    const people = [

      {name: 'david'},
      {name: 'patel'},
      {name: 'kevin'},
      {name: 'coco'},
      {name: 'brock'},
      {name: 'rock'}
  ];

      const list = document.getElementById('list');

      //function to set the list
      function setList(group){
          clearlist();
          for(const person of group)
              {
                  const item = document.createElement('a');
                  item.classList.add('list-group-item');
                  const text =document.createTextNode(person.name);
                  item.appendChild(text);
                  list.appendChild(item);
              }
          if(group.lenght==0){
              setnoresult();
          }
      }

      function clearlist(){
          while(list.firstChild)
              {
                  list.removeChild(list.firstChild);
              }
      }

      function setnoresult(){
          const item = document.createElement('li');
          item.classList.add('list-group-item');
          const text =document.createTextNode('no result found');
          item.appendChild(text);
          list.appendChild(item);
      }

      function getrelevancy(value, searchterm){
          if(value === searchterm)
              {
                  return 2;
              }
          else if(value.startsWith(searchterm))
          {
              return 1;
          }
          else if(value.includes(searchterm))
          {
              return 0;
          }
          else{
              return -1;
          }
      }

      const searchinput = document.getElementById('search');
      searchinput.addEventListener('input',(event) => {

          let value = event.target.value;
          if(value && value.trim().length >0)
              {
                  value = value.trim().toLowerCase();
                  setList(people.filter(person => {
                      return person.name.includes(value);
                  }).sort((personA, personB) =>{
                      return getrelevancy(personB.name, value- getrelevancy(personA.name ,value))
                  }));
              }
          else{
              clearlist();
          }
 //           console.log(event.target.value);
      })
```

Comment: You've already got the anchor (`a`) element, just an an `href` to it.

Answer (score 0):

You could something like a `link: 'page.com` to your object then add the link the `<a>` by doing `item.href = people[index].link`. Hard to explain, let me just show an example:

```
const people = [ {name: "Jeff", link: "page.com/jeff"}, {name: "Jo", link: "page.com/Jo"} ];
```

And then call `setList` like this:

```
setList(people.filter(person => { return people.indexOf(person.name) }));
```

or something like that. Then set the href and name by:

```
const text = document.createTextNode(people[group].name);
item.href = people[group].link;
```

I really hope you understand what I just said.

Comment: i tried it but it is showing me this error                                                       
    `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at setList (mytest.html:157)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (mytest.html:208)
setList @ mytest.html:157
(anonymous) @ mytest.html:208`   i dont know what to do please help

Comment: @CurtisCrentsil Did you use my exact code? Did you change anything to adapt to your code? Do you understand my code?

Comment: yah man,i copied and pasted man, please could you like post your full code, thanks

Comment: @CurtisCrentsil I don't know your full code, so I don't know what your page is supposed to look like. You have to understand my code to properly use it in your code. Attempt to understand my code then ask me to explain what you don't understand.